# Why I can not set struct

Tags: c, struct

Hello everyone I have a program that picks up some factors from the user
For the purpose of planning workers in the factory
1 ID
2 working hours
3 Wages
4 How many workers there are in the factory
The program ran and everything is fine but the program fails to print the requested values
For example for the value 2 employees, ID 23, 34
Wage hours etc. The program prints an ugly and large number and for the ID printed 2! And not 23 34
How do I fix the ID and everything?

I mention again the output looks like this!

---

**

```
**number of Factory workers
2
ID: 2
Hour lySal: -858993460
workdays: -858993460
salary: -858993460
worker day is: 2 worker hours is: -858993460
ID: 2
Hour lySal: -858993460
workdays: -858993460
salary: -858993460
worker day is: 2 worker hours is: -858993460
C:\Users\יובל\source\repos\lastpartproject\Debug\lastpartproject.exe (process 8488) exited with code 0.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . .**
```

**

---

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



typedef struct {
    int DayNumber; //1-31
    int WorkHours; // 1-12
} WorkDay;

typedef struct {
    long ID;//ת.ז.
    int HourlySal; // שכר לשעה
    int workdays; //מספר ימי עבודה של העובד בחודש הנוכחי
    WorkDay* wd; // מצביע למערך דינאמי של נתוני ימי העבודה בחודש נוכחי
    double salary; // סה"כ שכר עבודה של העובד בחודש נוכחי
} Worker;

Worker* InitFactory(int* pSize);
void PrintFactory(Worker* pWorker, int size);
void CalculateSalary(Worker* pWorker, int size);
void InputWorkDay(WorkDay* pWD);
void PrintWorkDay(WorkDay wd);
void InputWorker(Worker* pW);
void PrintWorker(Worker w);

int main() {
    Worker* pFactory = NULL;
    int size = 0;
    


    pFactory = InitFactory(&size);
    CalculateSalary(pFactory, size);
    PrintFactory(pFactory, size);
    
    // free memory -
}

void InputWorkDay(WorkDay* pWD)
{
    printf("input worker day and worker hours\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &(pWD->DayNumber), &(pWD->WorkHours));

}

void PrintWorkDay(WorkDay wd)
{
    printf("worker day is: %d worker hours is: %d\n", wd.DayNumber, wd.WorkHours);
}

void InputWorker(Worker* pW)
{


    printf("input ID\n");
    scanf("%d", &(pW->ID));
    
    printf("Hour lySal\n");
    scanf("%d", &(pW->HourlySal));

    printf("input workdays\n");
    scanf("%d", &(pW->workdays));
    
    printf("input salary\n");
    scanf("%d", &(pW->salary));

    InputWorkDay(pW->wd);
}

void PrintWorker(Worker w)
{
    printf("ID: %d\n", w.ID);
    printf("Hour lySal: %d\n", w.HourlySal);
    printf("workdays: %d\n", w.workdays);
    printf("salary: %d\n", w.salary);
    PrintWorkDay(w.wd[0]);
}

Worker* InitFactory(int* pSize)
{
    int number_student = 0;
    Worker* Pfactory = NULL;
    printf("number of Factory workers\n");
    scanf("%d", &number_student);
    *pSize = number_student;

    Pfactory = (Worker*)malloc(*pSize * sizeof(Worker));
    if (Pfactory == NULL)
    {
        printf("no storage\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < *pSize; i++)
    {
        Pfactory[i].wd = (WorkDay*)malloc(31 * sizeof(WorkDay));

        InputWorker(&Pfactory[i]);
    }
}

void PrintFactory(Worker* pWorker, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {

        PrintWorker(*pWorker);
    }
}

void CalculateSalary(Worker* pWorker, int size)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
    {
        //pWorker[j].HourlySal* pWorker[j].workdays;
    }
}
```

Comment: Apart from the compilation error caused by the missing function `CalculateSalary()` MS compiler gives three warnings - all important. Please follow them up.

Comment: Wrong format specifiers - should be `%lf` - in `scanf("%d", &(pW->salary));` and in `printf("salary: %d\n", w.salary);`

Answer (score 1):

At least these problem:

Assignment fails as `InitFactory()` does not return a value.

```
pFactory = InitFactory(&size);
```

Found this quickly by having many warnings enabled:

```
warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

Save time, be more productive.  **Enable all warnings.**

---

Other samples:

```
scanf("%d", &(pW->salary));
warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'long int' [-Wformat=]

printf("salary: %d\n", w.salary);
warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'double' [-Wformat=]
```

There are more like errors to find.

Comment: @dereyyovel "Enable all warnings." --> Edit your compiler settings.  With gcc, add "-pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -c -fmessage-length=0".  With other compilers, refer to documentation.

Comment: @dereyyovel [What should be done to restore value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65645696/why-i-can-not-set-struct/65645967?noredirect=1#comment116064775_65645967) please be more specific.  What _value_?  Have you enabled all warnings?

Comment: @dereyyovel Notice `Worker* InitFactory(int* pSize)` does not _return_ anything.  Try `return Pfactory;` at that function's end.

Comment: right!! Need to do RETURN !!
It returns the value but not all the variables
If I did two employees then it looks like this
(Entrance)
One employee
ID card 234235
Working hours 34

Employee number 2
ID card 1211112
Working hours 125

(Output)
One employee
ID card 234235
Working hours 34

Employee number 2
ID card 234235
Working hours 34

How do I fix?

Comment: @dereyyovel "How do I fix?" --> Have you [enabled all warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65645696/why-i-can-not-set-struct/65645967?noredirect=1#comment116064846_65645967)?  I certainly do not want to spend time fixing things that a compiler can readily warn about.